# Formidable file upload is uploading the file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to make this work since yesterday and yet I cannot find a guide/tutorial that either I can follow or that works.

I'm trying this guide https://medium.com/@ShiyaLuo/simple-file-upload-with-express-js-and-formidable-in-node-js-d734d248d615 but when I hit the upload button nothing happens. I'll resume the steps:

1. Create a new folder
2. cd into that folder
3. Open a terminal and copy&paste this `npm init -y`
4. copy&paste `npm install express formidable`
5. Create `app.js` and paste this code

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('formidable');

var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/', function (req, res){
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req);

    form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
        file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
    });

    form.on('file', function (name, file){
        console.log('Uploaded ' + file.name);
    });

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

5. create `index.html` and copy&paste this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="upload" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

6. Go to `http://localhost:3000/` and try it out

You'll see the input file and the upload button, once you select the file(.jpg) you click the button and what's supose to happen is to upload the file in the upload folder but it doesn't happen, is it just me or something is missing there? because that's pretty much the same code you'll find in many sites and youtube tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, I learned that you had to replace the current filepath value with the new one in the File Object, which is given by `file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;` but here's the problem, the name of the variable was `filepath` instead of `path`, and the name of the file was `originalFilename` instead of `name`, I'll show you, look at this:

```
form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
    console.log(file)
    file.path = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.name;
});
```

I took this from the original code above. Do you see that `console.log(file)` ? this is what it shows in console:

```
PersistentFile {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { error: [Function (anonymous)] },
  _eventsCount: 1,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  lastModifiedDate: null,
  filepath: 'C:\\Users\\CAMPES~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\826f34463d178155ab6434e00',
  newFilename: '826f34463d178155ab6434e00',
  originalFilename: 'aaa.jpeg',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  hashAlgorithm: false,
  size: 0,
  _writeStream: null,
  hash: null,
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

We can see the name of the variables are `filepath` and `originalFilename`, so the portion of the code above must look like this

```
form.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){
    file.filepath = __dirname + '/uploads/' + file.originalFilename;
});
```

And the rest of the code remains the same and that's it, I'm not sure whether this thread should be deleted, but I'll leave this here just in case someone needs it.